# Paypal API: How to add multiple merchants on single invoice?

Tags: php, paypal

I have a website that allows sellers to create invoice and send to buyer.

I also have to deduct website's 10% commission from that invoice amount. 
I want to cut the 10% commission from the total amount and send remaining amount to the seller upon successful payment through API.

Is there any possibility to create that invoice with multiple merchants ( website owner and seller ) with their share percent ? or kindly tell me if there is any better solution to achieve that goal.

Comment: Formerly PayPal has the API called Adaptive Payment, but they are deprecating this API starting from December 2017. You can try to explore MassPayments in PayPal.

Comment: MassPayment is also deprecated

Comment: You can tryout Payout

Comment: Yes I am looking into that. Thanks for your help